# document.readyState is not changing in Chrome and Mozilla but changes in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, document-ready

`document.readyState` is able to track values such as 'complete' ,'interactive' in IE. but in Chrome `document.readyState` is getting set to 'complete' and no 'interactive' state is tracked.

As the state is not getting changed from 'complete' `document.onreadystatechange` is not getting triggered.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
    ReleaseSpinner(my Custom code);
  }
}
```